# How to remove ONLY a group with ruby regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching, gsub

I'm trying to remove a pattern from a string using the ruby `gsub` method. Given the following string:

`ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICH-
    TING`

I need to remove only the hyphen at end of line and turn the string into a single line, like `ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICHTING`. I tried:

```
name = <<-TEXT
  ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICH-
  TING
TEXT

name.gsub(/[a-zA-Z](\-\n)/, '')
```

But it don't worked. The gsub should remove ONLY the `(\-\n)` immediately after any non-numeric character (`[a-zA-Z]`).

Searching here, at SO, I figured out through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457321/ruby-regex-gsub-only-captured-group) that `gsub` ignore the regexp group and do the substitution for all the pattern. Are there an option to gsub in ruby, or a different way on using this method that I can achieve this result?

Answer (score 2):

```
name.gsub!(/(?<=[A-Za-z])-\n\s*/, '')
```

"Replace a dash, a newline and any number of spaces that are preceded by a letter, with nothing"

A lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) is not considered to be a part of the match. Alternately, you could capture the letter in a capture group and then re-insert it in the replacement, but it is less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
▶ name = <<-TEXT
▷   ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICH-
▷   TING
▷ TEXT
#⇒ "  ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICH-\n  TING\n"
▶ name.split(/-\n\s*/).join
#⇒ "  ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICHTING\n"
```

or, to get rid of leading/trailing spaces:

```
▶ name.split(/-\n/).map(&:strip).join
#⇒ "ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICHTING"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you must use a regex?

```
name.split('-').map(&:strip).join
  #=> "ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICHTING"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
your_string.gsub!(/-\n\s*/, '')
#=> "ANTIONO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLITICH\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
name = <<-TEXT
  ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICH-
  TING
TEXT


puts name.gsub(/^\s+/,'').gsub(/(?<=[a-zA-Z])(\-\n)/,'')
```

OUTPUT:

```
ANTONIO JUAREZ HAMPEL SCHLICHTING
```